# Objective-C/Cocoa tutorial for internet capable application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I've done a bit of iPhone programming (even have 1 published app) but what I'm really interested in doing is learning to create applications for OS X.
I'm a 7 year .Net Developer so I have some understanding of how to make desktop applications, though I don't know much about memory management as .Net spoiled me.
I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a good tutorial for Objective-C/Cocoa but SPECIFICALLY targeting networking protocols as the application I have in mind would need to have networking capabilities (it's a turn based game with included chat).
Everywhere I look for tutorials these days leads me to iPhone and Cocoa-Touch tutorials but I need desktop tutorials.

Comment: If you use Garbage Collection on the Desktop the memory management problems go away (generally).

Comment: @Abizem - How exactly do you use Garbage Collection then?

Comment: How exactly? I enable the build setting then follow this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/GarbageCollection/Introduction.html

Comment: +1 Really, why bother downvotng?

Comment: I downvoted NSD because his answer was not even a real answer, more of a comment, and then his followup comment was basically an insult.
Why shouldn't that be downvoted?

Comment: My comment here was to counteract the downvoting on your question. My upvote was on NSD's answer was because a)I thought it was a valid answer and b)because if you disagree with a comment, flag it for moderation rather than retro-actively penalise the answer. I don't agree with NSD, but my voting reflects what I think of questions and answers, not what I feel about the person asking or answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably gonna have to tackle the two subjects separately. For general desktop app development, Aaron Hillegass' book *[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)* is the most often recommended. It also covers memory management, though if you've already gotten an iPhone application published, I presume you've already tackled the subject.

For networking, Apple provides *[Getting Started with Networking, Internet, and Web](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_NetworkingInternetWeb/index.html)*, which is a bit broad, but leads to *[Introduction to Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html)*, which in turn contains the chapter *[Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI)*.

Also keep in mind, OS X is a Unix™ platform, and Objective-C is a superset of C. This means you can eschew Cocoa entirely and use the BSD socket API directly using standard C syntax—meaning you can just Google ["bsd socket tutorial"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=bsd+socket+tutorial&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) and you're off to the races.

Comment: +1 Aaron Hillegass' book Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X

Comment: Hillegass is hopelessly stuck in 1988. There is nothing in his book that isn't in Apple's free materials.

Answer (score 1):

The XCode installation comes with a ton of example code in the /Developer/Examples folder.

There are even more on the ADC site, such as [GeekGameBoard](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/GeekGameBoard/).

Answer (score -1):

Apple has a ton of them. Beginner tutorials are not going to have much to do with online games because they're for beginners.

Comment: I wouldn't call myself a beginner.  I'm an intermediate looking to find out more information about networking os x apps.
Maybe I should be doing beginner Cocoa tutorials while doing intermediate Objective-C networking tutorials.

Comment: +1 to counteract negative voting.